# AutoMapper overrides source properties

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, automapper, dto

I have the following code to update `Student` entity:

```
using static AutoMapper.Mapper;
...
public void Update(StudentInputDto dto)
{
   Student student = _studentRepository.GetStudent();
   student = Map<Student>(dto); //student.studentnumer is null here :(
   _studentRepository.Update(student);
}
```

**My student Entity:**

```
public class Student
{
   public Guid studentid { get; set; }
   public string firstname { get; set; }
   public string lastname { get; set; }
   public int age { get; set; }
   public Guid genderid { get; set; }
   public string studentnumber { get; set; }
}
```

**My StudentInputDto:**

```
public class StudentInputDto
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
   public Guid GenderId { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that Student.studentnumber is null after the mapping.

I want to configure AutoMapper in such a way that Student.studentnumber is preserved after the mapping. How to do it ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My initial thought was to configure AutoMapper in a following way:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
   cfg.CreateMap<StudentInputDto, Student>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.studentnumber, opt => opt.Ignore());
});
```

But that configuration, does not solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automapper - can it map over only existing properties in source and destination objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147099/automapper-can-it-map-over-only-existing-properties-in-source-and-destination)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at method description of **Automapper**.

```
TDestination Map<TDestination>(object source);
```

> Execute a mapping from the source object to a new destination object. The source type is inferred from the source object.

`student = Map<Student>(dto)` will create a new `Student` object and assign to `student` variable

To map two existing objects use `Mapper.Map(dto, student);` instead

```
TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source, TDestination destination)
```

> Execute a mapping from the source object to the existing destination
>   object.